# Conditionally adding tags options parameter to select2

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-select2

I have multiple elements on a page that are triggering a load of select2 to the element. I'm trying to conditionally check if the element has a certain class, and if so add the `tag` option; otherwise do not. I thought something like this would work, but it's not:

```
$('.element_to_add_select_two_on').select2({
    tags:function(element) {
        return (element.className === 'classname_i_am_targeting');
    },
});
```

What am I missing here? I'm subjecting myself to the following buffoonery to get this to target and load:

```
$('.element_to_add_select_two_on').each((index,element) => {
    let showTags = false;

    if ($(element).attr('class').split(' ').includes('classname_i_am_targeting')) {
        showTags = true;
    }

    $(element).select2({
        tags:showTags,
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you saying the second piece of code works but not the first?

Comment: Exactly. @JasonRoman

Comment: Hey @Zach Smith, did my answer end up working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems with your first attempt. First, you are defining `tags` as a function when what you want is the *result* of the function, since `tags` needs to be defined as a boolean **true** or **false**. The other is that inside your `.select2()` call, you do not have access to the calling element `$('.element_to_add_select_two_on')` in the way that you think. It isn't an event that you are listening on, it's a function call that wants an object passed with its configuration.

You conveyed that your second method works, but it can be simplified with the jQuery [`hasClass()`](https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes) function:

```
$('.element_to_add_select_two_on').each((index, element) => {
  $(element).select2({
    tags: $(element).hasClass('classname_i_am_targeting'),
  });
});
```

There is a much simpler way to do all of this, however, and it is much more flexible and already built into select2 via the way of [data-* attributes](https://select2.org/configuration/data-attributes) (note, you need jQuery > 1.x). You can simply add `data-tags="true"` to any of your `select` elements with which you want tags enabled. These will override any configuration options used when initializing select2 as well as any defaults:

```
<select data-tags="true">
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the simplified jQuery. That aspect works great.
Targeting via the `data-attr` logic sounds great, but isn't working for my setup. It could be a variety of reasons exclusive to the implementation of `select2` that I'm using.